# Reputation to Accept Answer

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, privileges

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62140795/how-to-best-structure-this-data-in-mysql-tables/62140947?noredirect=1#comment110016439_62140947), the asker (a new user) said in a comment:

> Because I am knew to stack overflow, I am unable to upvote or mark your answer as correct, unfortunately.

He had 11 rep at the time. **It had also been three days since he originally asked the question.**

I checked the reputation table, and confirmed he couldn't vote it up (needs 15). However, I don't see anything in the table regarding accepting an answer.

Is there a reputation threshold new users have to meet before they can accept answers on their own questions?

Comment: There's no rep requirement for accepting. There's a couple time limitations, but it's tiny for answers where the answerer isn't the asker. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/332043 for the details

Comment: no you can accept also with 1 rep

Comment: @Zoe Any reason why your comment isn't an answer? It meets my needs.

Comment: He could have accepted it, accept does not require any rep. Probably he did not find the pipe icon on the left. It is useful if you help rep1 users for that in a comment.

Comment: @usr2564301 The comment was more than 15 minutes after the question was asked.

Comment: I've gotten great feedback here. Since asking, I've commented on the referenced question to give the user some instructions on accepting an answer (the link from @Zoe was included). I'd consider this question resolved at this point, but as mentioned before, there's not actually an answer for me to accept. I'll keep an eye on this for a few more days just in case. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a duplicate - it had been MUCH more than 15 minutes after the question was posted.

Comment: If you see this in the reopen queue: please *actually look at the linked question*. The duplicate is clearly inapplicable here.

Comment: I think the linked question *does* conclusively answer this: *there is no limit, other than the 15 minutes delay*. Most likely the OP immediately tried to check the answer but it didn't work at the time. When asked much later, they didn't try again and just repeated the initial "it dint work".

Comment: @usr2564301 Unless I missed something, nothing in that question or any of the answers says that it's the *only* requirement.

Comment: @usr2564301, no the question was originally answered days after. The 15 minute limit was not in play.

Comment: The new duplicate link is closer, but still not totally applicable. The user is a newbie, but he clearly stated that the question was correct, but also claimed he was unable to answer because of rep. I wanted to confirm that he was incorrect before telling him he was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no rep requirement for accepting. There's a couple time limitations, but it's tiny (15 minutes) for answers where the answerer isn't the asker. See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for the details.

<sub>(Original version of the answer is converted from [Zoe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398004/reputation-to-accept-answer#comment773569_398004))</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I wanted to know. The link (originally from Zoe) looked perfect for providing to the new user, so I passed it on. The user has since accepted the answer.